# How i change .setImage in embed without restart bot or write cmd again?

Tags: javascript, html, discord, discord.js

as u can see name topic how do I make the .setImage change every update when i change the image without deleting a msg? or write cmd once again

my first attempt : I tried to make it by uploading the image from a hosting site and to get the image link and from there I change the image and then I used setInterval to update the line .setImage but did not work for me this is my code of first attempt

```js
let exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        exampleEmbed.setImage('https://test.000webhostapp.com/images/image.jpg')
        .setTimestamp()

    try {
        let message1 = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        setInterval(async function(){
            let exampleEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            exampleEmbed2.setImage('https://test.000webhostapp.com/images/image.jpg')
            console.log('updated')
            await message1.edit({ embeds: [exampleEmbed2] })
        },7000)

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
```

my second attempt was from the local computer I used MessageAttachment to get me the file path of image and then I also used setInterval to update the line function inside .setImage + MessageAttachment every 7 seconds it didn't work either. Although when I type the command again, the (updated) image appears on the second try
here is my codes try second attempt

```js
let exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        exampleEmbed.setImage('https://test.000webhostapp.com/images/image.jpg')
        .setTimestamp()

    try {
        let message1 = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        setInterval(async function(){
            let exampleEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed()
      const attachement =  new MessageAttachment('./images/image.jpg','image.jpg');
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            exampleEmbed2.setImage('attachment://image.jpg')
            console.log('updated')
            await message1.edit({ embeds: [exampleEmbed2], files: [attachement] })
        },7000)

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
```

Is there another way please? i would like to do the image update sync in any way without restart the bot or even writing cmd again

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong this is caused by Discord's image caching.

To force it to get fresh image (when you edit the message embed) you can put URL parameters (i.e. timestamp). This way you will trick it to think it's a new uncached image.

Example:

```js
'https://test.000webhostapp.com/images/image.jpg?something=' + new Date().getTime()
```

Comment: I did this like this so I'm not wrong i put parameters in .addImage next to the URL and it didn't work i mean why did the image not come too?

`exampleEmbed2.setImage('https://test.000webhostapp.com/images/image.jpg' + new Date().getTime() )`

Comment: Because to put a parameter to an URL you need to put "?". The way you did it is wrong cuz it will look for the file "image.jpg1234567" which doesn't exist. ```exampleEmbed2.setImage('https://test.000webhostapp.com/images/image.jpg?' + new Date().getTime())``` should do the trick.